# Multiple conditions in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to pass a parameter into a condition to select rows, if I pass 0 it should select all rows, 1 - only HDD, 2 - All except HDD

Please see code:

```
declare @Accessories table (id int, name nvarchar(20), atype nvarchar(20), itype int)

insert into @Accessories values (1, 'Seagate HDD 100GB', 'HDD', 1)
insert into @Accessories values (2, 'Samsung HDD 100GB', 'HDD', 1)
insert into @Accessories values (3, 'WD HDD 500GB', 'HDD', 1)
insert into @Accessories values (4, 'Samsung 4GB', 'RAM', 2)
insert into @Accessories values (5, 'GeForce 512MB', 'Video', 3)

declare @param int

set @param = 1 /* 0 - All records, 1 - Only HDD, 2 - All exclude HDD */

select 
    * 
from @Accessories
where itype = @param /* NEED RIGHT CONDITION HERE*/
```

I can't write code like if @param = 0 then ... 
Is it way to write condition in WHERE statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
select * 
from @Accessories 
where (@Param = 0)
  or (@Param = 1 and atype = 'HDD') 
--or (@Param = 1 and itype = 1) , if itype and atype are connected
  or (@Param = 2 and atype != 'HDD')
option (recompile)
```

If Param is 0 the first condition becomes `0=0` and matches for all rows, so all rows are returned. If param is 1 or 2, only the respective or branch matches on the first condition, so it returns what the second condition specifies.

Also, the `option (recompile)` is really important (view the article in Martin's comment). It instructs SQL server to use the runtime values of the parameters when preparing an execution plan, so basically:

- when @Param = 0 the query becomes `select * from @Accessories`
- when @Param = 1 the query becomes `select * from @Accessories where atype = 'HDD'`
- when @Param = 2 the query becomes `select * from @Accessories where atype != 'HDD'`

Comment: This `catch all` query might lead to suboptimal plans. `option (recompile)` or splitting the cases up might be better. [Related Article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Comment: SWeko's answer should work well, just remember that it's using `OR`s, so if you have additional criteria be sure to group it correctly with parentheses. Also, put the column names instead of using `*`.

Comment: @Martin: agreed, added to answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE itype BETWEEN @param AND CASE 
    WHEN @param = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 2000000000 END
OPTION (RECOMPILE); -- thanks for the reminder @Martin
```

Comment: I think your query would not work because you are using itype like is integer data type.

Comment: @Henry: itype **IS** an `INT`. What data type do you think it should be treated like?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Accessories table (id int, name nvarchar(20), atype nvarchar(20))

insert into @Accessories values (1, 'Seagate HDD 100GB', 'HDD')
insert into @Accessories values (2, 'Samsung HDD 100GB', 'HDD')
insert into @Accessories values (3, 'WD HDD 500GB', 'HDD')
insert into @Accessories values (4, 'Samsung 4GB', 'RAM')
insert into @Accessories values (5, 'GeForce 512MB', 'Video')

declare @param int

set @param = 0 /* 0 - All records, 1 - Only HDD, 2 - All exclude HDD */

if(@param =0)
begin
select * from @Accessories
end
if(@param =1)
begin
select * from @Accessories where atype in ('HDD')
end
if(@param =2)
begin
select * from @Accessories where atype not in('HDD')
end
```

Comment: What if 5 new parameters are added? What is the query is significantly more complex? This means you have (number of @param values) queries to maintain. You can also lead to the same recompile issues where the plan can be stuck on an atypical parameter.

Comment: Aaron Bertrand  is right. My sql is huge. Seems I clearly wrote in my question "I can't write code like if @param = 0 then"