# How to write a where clause that has multiple cases?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that has a nullable parameter, and following is my query

```
select * 
from table1
where table1.id = isnull(@id, table1.id)
```

Now there are some special ids I treat them differently. I am adding another table table2 like below

```
combid    id
1         abc01
1         abc02
1         abc03
2         hig01
2         hig02
```

I have to change the query to satisfy following cases

1. If `@id` is null, the where clause will be `table1.id = table1.id`
2. If `@id` is not null,
   2.1 if `@id` exists in table2, the where clause will be `table1.id in (select id from table2 where combid in (select combid from table2 where id=@id))`
   2.2 otherwise the where clause will be `table1.id = @id`

I have tried following query, but doesn't work.

```
select  * from table1
where (table1.id=@id and not exists(select * from table2 where id=@id)
or @id is null
or table1.id in (select id from table2 where combid in (select combid where id=@id)) and  exists(select * from table2 where id=@id))
```

How do I change the stored procedure's query?

Comment: [What, exactly, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403301/multiple-conditions-in-where-clause will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE
    @id IS NULL
    OR
    (
        @id IS NOT NULL
        AND
        (      
            (
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE id = @id)
                AND
                table1.id IN (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE combid in (SELECT combid FROM table2 WHERE id=@id))
            ) 
            OR
            (
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE id = @id)
                AND         
                table1.id = @id
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: this is really slow, i have to kill it.

Comment: doesn't quite right. I got records that have table1.id is empty too. And if I pass null, I got 0 record.

Comment: I'm sorry but only way that query could return 0 rows for passed null is when table1 is empty. So either you have not implemented or explained it correctly, or I haven't understood the request, but this query works fine. Here is SQL Fiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e05c0/2 with all 3 cases. You can check  how it works. If something is different in your tables, please use sql fiddle to provide provide better sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if...else...instead of writing only one SELECT statement, using **if else** for your case is easier to read.

```
if(@id is null)
    select * from table1
else if exists (select 1 from table2 where id = @id)
    select * from table1 
    where table1.id in 
                  (select id from table2 where combid in 
                         (select combid from table2 where id=@id)
                  )
else 
   select * from table1 where table1.id=@id
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need put all the logic in the where clause.

Comment: I can't use this method also because I will insert the result into a temp table.

Comment: Why you have to put all logic in the where clause? you can still insert into temp table in IF...ELSE...just before each select, add insert into @temptable...